# how to create axis cliente from etframeworksf.wsdl

Tags: marketing-cloud, webservices, wsdl

We are trying to generate the stub client for the salesforce api at this url:

https://etappx.exacttarget.com/etframeworksf.wsdl

But when we put in the command line the follow command:

```
java -cp "$AXISCLASSPATH" org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java https://etappx.exacttarget.com/etframeworksf.wsdl
```

we get the output:

```
java.io.IOException: Type {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}DataExtensionFieldSt orageType is referenced but not defined.
            at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.checkForUndefined(Symbol Table.java:665)
            at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:545 )
            at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.jav a:518)
            at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.jav a:495)
            at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

so the question is:

How we can fix the namespaces to axis can generated the stub clients class?

Comment: I feel its more suited on StackOverflow rather than Salesforce StackExchange,

Comment: post it, if is answered in so, i'll copy the a. here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475568/how-to-create-axis1-cliente-from-etframeworksf-wsdl-from-saleforce